# Laravel relationships - are there multiple *unnecessary* database calls?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have 2 models: `Post` and `User` where each `Post` has one `User` and each `User` has many `Post`s.

User.php:

```
// User.php

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Post.php:

```
// Post.php

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

I load a post through my `PostsController`:

```
// PostsController.php

public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

In the view, I make calls to both the post that I loaded in *and* to the user related to the post. I make multiple calls to the user object:

```
// views/posts/show.blade.php

<h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>
<p>{{ $post->user->name }}</p>
<p>{{ $post->user->email }}</p>
```

Will these 2 calls to the `$post->user` resource make 2 calls to the database?

How does the Eloquent relationship work in the back end? Does the relationship always return the entire `user` object when I get the `post` object, or does it lazily get the `user` data?

I am concerned about hosting my database with a provider that charges based on data transferred from the database (GCP) and I don't understand how the Eloquent relationship will call the database.

Comment: [From docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties):  Dynamic properties are "lazy loading", meaning they will only load their relationship data when you actually access them

Comment: And it will run only once for `$post->user`

Comment: I feel this question is too broad. What you're asking is covered in the docs, and in the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel provides a feature called [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) which lets you load the model and any relationships by optimizing the queries:

```
Post::with('user')->find($id);
```

Eager loading works with many relationships as well. The following would also result in just two queries, regardless of the amount of posts a user has:

```
User::with('posts')->find($id);
```

This will load the Post entity's user model so that accessing it will not require a second query. You can read more about eager loading and other performance enhancements in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5).

Comment: Eager loading will do 2 queries: ...  __Thankfully, we can use eager loading to reduce this operation to just 2 queries. When querying, you may specify which relationships should be eager loaded using the with method__ ...

Comment: I would update the answer a bit, to cover the question __Will these 2 calls to the $post->user resource make 2 calls to the database?__ . Look at my comments below the question, and expand on that ;)

Comment: Any additional questions are covered in depth in the docs. I can copy paste the docs or just link out to them, as I already have :)

Comment: That was literally the question __Will these 2 calls ...__. In his example, there are 2 queries, 1 for posts and 1 for user. He was wondering are there 3 queries executed and how it works?